# Doing a class inheriting from a database cursor

Tags: database, class, oop, architecture, cursor

Is it a good way to create my SQL requester class ?

I want a class where i put all my requests.

My application has only one user. So i would like to have only one cursor (=the instance of the Requester)

If my approach is bad, please tell me why.

```
class Requester(sqlite3.Cursor):
    def __init__(self, inpath):
        # Instantiate the cursor
        super().__init__(sqlite3.connect(inpath))

    def request_1(self):
        # Build the SQL request
        sql_request = ("SELECT * FROM table_a")

        # Execute the request
        raw = self.execute(sql_request).fetchall()

        # Rearrange raw variable here

        return result
```